# UIRotationGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have a very weird problem, I am implementing UIRotationGestureRecognizer in my application to rotate an image. My problem is that sometimes when you start rotating the image it jumps to the other finger. 
Example: I am dragging my image with one finger, and after that I use my second finger to start rotating, but the image goes to the second finger. Is that normal? can it be fixed?
The code I am using is:

```
if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    prevRotation = 0.0;
    return;
}

CGFloat newRotation = 0.0 - (prevRotation - [recognizer rotation]);

CGAffineTransform currentTransformation = image.transform;
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransformation, newRotation);

image.transform = newTransform;

prevRotation = [recognizer rotation];
```

I tried saving the last location of the center and applying it again, but it is not working either, like this:

```
lastPoint=image.center;

if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    prevRotation = 0.0;
    return;
}

CGFloat newRotation = 0.0 - (prevRotation - [recognizer rotation]);

CGAffineTransform currentTransformation = image.transform;
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransformation, newRotation);

image.transform = newTransform;

prevRotation = [recognizer rotation];
image.center=lastPoint;
```

Comment: Your dragging is from UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Comment: no, my dragging is with a detection if the touch is inside the view, if it is in the touchesMoved I change the center of my image to the touch.

Comment: You are probably just taking any touch out of touches moved.  You can't do this because then it will take either finger and jump to that finger.  You need to keep track of how many fingers are on the screen and not do the dragging when two fingers are down, or calculate the average of the two fingers.  Or save yourself some trouble and use UIPan.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
-(void)rotate:(id)sender
{

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];

    self.imageTag = [[sender view]tag];
    NSLog(@"sender tag %d", self.imageTag);
    if([(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        lastRotation = 0.0;
        return;
    }

    CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (lastRotation - [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation]);

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform,rotation);

    [[(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];

    lastRotation = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation];
}
```

Comment: Its very weird, the image continues to jump from one finger to another, maybe the size of my image is affecting the performance? it has a size of 50x50